# CS0246 visual studio community edition 2015 missing reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a "windows 10 pro" and a fresh install of "visual studio community edition 2015" installed.

I do a new project console application and call it ftptest
then copy and paste the code from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ftpcheck
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com");

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And try to build it just to see what it does.

I get a lot of:

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'FtpWebRequest' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'NetworkCredential' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can i add that missing reference?

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Net?

Comment: Make sure you are targetting full .NET Framework, version 4.5 or newer, and not the client profile or CLR Core or Silverlight.

Comment: @user89861: FtpWebRequest and NetworkCredential are not in System.Net.dll, they're in System.dll.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using the wrong project template to get started.  Use Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Console Application.  And you somehow lost the *static* keyword on the Main() method.

Comment: @hans passant that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered with a comment by hans passant:

My crystal ball says that you are using the wrong project template to get started. Use Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Console Application. And you somehow lost the static keyword on the Main() method. – Hans Passant Nov 26 '15 at 20:48

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on msdn, you will see the reference that you have to add:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Namespace:   System.Net
Assembly:  System (in System.dll)
```

Comment: isn't it already added with that part of the code?                                            using System.Net;

Comment: @Malkavian He has the using statement, but that doesn't mean the .dll is being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

include:  using System.Net; in your references section